# How to create dynamic field in Jira?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to create some dynamic field in Jira similar to what we do in JavaScript.

e.g. there is a dropdown list, with value a, b and c. If I select a, there will pop up some fields only for a; if I select b, there will pop up some fields only for b.

Can this be done in Jira, or are there any plugins that solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [JIRA Behaviours Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JBHV/JIRA+Behaviours+Plugin) to change any field according to any selected field, for example:

```
FormField dropdown = getFieldByName("My Dropdown")
FormField other= getFieldByName("Other field")

if (dropdown.getFormValue() == 'A') {
 other.setHidden(false) // set custom filed vlaues
 other.setFormValue("A choosen")
} else {
 other.setHidden(true) // hide any fields you like
}
```